# Zip files contained in a file over a loop

Tags: bash, zip

I have a file with X paths to files I want to zip.

I have this loop:

```
while read -r path; do
  zip -u "$zip_file" "$path"
done <"$paths_file"
```

I have this error:

> zip warning: missing end signature--probably not a zip file (did you warning: remember to use binary mode when you transferred it?)
> zip warning: (if you are trying to read a damaged archive try -F)

I do not find informations about it, I tried with `-F` option but doesn't work.

How can I achieve it ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) explain what `$zip_file` is and where that is defined; ii) show us what is in the `$paths_file` file and iii) tell us your operating system since that is usually relevant.

Comment: One raw idea (work only if you do not have special symbols in paths): `zip -r zipfile.zip $(cat "$paths_file")`

Answer (score 0):

That seems pretty convoluted alternative to using a functionality that the default Info-ZIP `zip` brings out of the box: It can read the names of files directly from a file.

```
zip -u "$zip_file" "@$paths_file"
```